# Redirect site using .htaccess if url contains certain parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect my site using .htaccess if the url contains a certain parameter.

For example when my site contains `?lang=de`, then I would like to have the site to be permanently redirected to `https://www.example.com/de/`

This is what I've tried:

```
# BEGIN Redirects for mobile params
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} lang=de
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/de/
# END Redirects for mobile params
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

UPDATE: This is what I'm trying now, but I'm getting:

```
# BEGIN Redirects for mobile params
RewriteEngine on
# if the query string contains a parameter called "lang"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=de
# then redirect (permanently) to /
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/de/ [L,R=permanent]
# END Redirects for mobile params
```

But this is resulting in ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

UPDATE: I found that when it put this at the end of my .htaccess that it starts to work.

Comment: Since your rewrite target does not contain a query string, the original query string will get appended to it again. Use the `QSD` flag to prevent that, if you are on Apache 2.4; if it is a lower version, you can also get the original query string discarded by appending just a question mark to the end of your target URL.

Comment: What about URLs of the form `/foo?lang=de` - should the URL-path be preserved in the redirect? ie. `/de/foo`

Answer (score 0):

> I found that when it put this at the end of my `.htaccess` that it starts to work.

This may be due to earlier directives that prevent the redirect loop (in other words there is a conflict). Ideally, this redirect should be near the start of the `.htaccess` file.

However, you should still discard the query string from the redirected response. As it stands, your redirect to `/de/` will still contain the `lang=de` URL parameter. The `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4 will do this. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=(de)
RewriteRule !de/ /%1/ [QSD,R=permanent,L]
```

The `%1` backreference contains the "de" captured in the query string.